# How to update state in a component when the value changed at vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In vuex store I have this mutations which receives msg from one component and is to show/hide prompt message at another component (Like `You are logged in` propmpt after successful login) :

```
setPromptMsg: function (state, msg) {
    state.showPromptMsg = true;
    state.promptMsg = msg;
        function sleep (time) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
      }                           
     sleep(3000).then(() => {
          store.showPromptMsg = false;
          state.promptMsg = '';
          console.log('show message set to false');
      });
},
```

In the compoenet, I receive `showPromptMsg` from the store as a computed property:

```
computed: {
    showPromptMsg () {
        return this.$store.state.showPromptMsg;
    },
    promptMsg () {
    return this.$store.state.promptMsg;
    }
}
```

The show/hide prompt message in the template:

```
   <div v-show="showPromptMsg">
      <div class="text-center" >
         <strong> {{promptMsg}} </strong>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that when the prompt is timedout, i.e. `showPromptMsg` is set to false at the store, the change is not reflected into the component, so the notification box does not disappear.

I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is setting

```
store.showPromptMsg = false;
```

I expect you want

```
state.showPromptMsg = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `NotificationBarComponent.vue` template:

```
<div>
    <div class="text-center" >
       <strong> {{ message }} </strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your `NotificationBarComponent.vue` component definition add a prop to pass custom message to display and on mounted start the timeout to hide the notification:

```
export.default {
    props: ['message'],
    mounted() {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.$store.commit('handleMessageState', false)
        }, 3000);
    }   
};
```

in your store create a property to manage the notification display `isNotificationBarDisplayed: false`

```
handleMessageState(state, payload) {
    state.isNotificationBarDisplayed = payload;
}
```

anywhere you want to use it:

```
<notification-bar-component v-show="isNotificationBarDisplayed" message="Some message here"></notification-bar-component>

computed: {
    isNotificationBarDisplayed () {
        return this.$store.state.isNotificationBarDisplayed;
    },
}
```